# Webpack / typescript require works but import doesn't

Tags: import, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to import a node_module into a TypeScript file. I'm using an adaptation of [angular2-webpack-starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter) for my project structure.

```
import ace from 'brace';
```

In one of my files gives me

> Cannot find module 'brace'.

But

```
var ace = require('brace');
```

Works fine. According to [this issue](https://github.com/thlorenz/brace/issues/46) I shouldn't be having any problems.

My webpack config file is copied from angular2-webpack-starter.
My tsconfig.json is as follows

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "files": [
    "src/bootstrap.ts",
    "src/vendor.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
   "filesGlob": [
      "./src/**/*.ts",
      "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "compileOnSave": false,
   "buildOnSave": false
}
```

Why would one work but not the other?

Comment: the issue you mentioned seems to be related to babel not tsc. can you post the js tsc outputs for the import statements?

Comment: did you try `import * as ace from 'brace'`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is related to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/247). If a module doesn't have type data available (via a `.d.ts` file), the ES6 module syntax

```
import name from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { member } from "module-name";
//etc
```

will not work and one must use the CommonJS alternative,

```
var name = require("module-name");
```

Comment: This is no longer true as of the 2.1 release of TypeScript.

Comment: @Samir standard ES2015 import / export semantics. [Here are the release notes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#untyped-imports)