# Vuejs - Can't resolve 'moment' in 'app/src' | After a project clone and npm install

Tags: vue.js, npm, momentjs

I cloned an existant Vuejs project and made a "npm install". 
Everything installed well except "moment" and maybe "vue-moment".

i've got this error :

```
Failed to compile.
./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'moment' in '/app/src'
```

so in installed them with "npm install --save moment vue-moment"

And still got the error.

here some code of my main.js file :

```
import moment from 'moment'
import VueMoment from 'vue-moment'

// Vue use moment.js
Vue.use(VueMoment, {
  moment
});
moment.locale('fr');
```

the packages are installed and present in the node_modules folder and are present also in the package.log.json and package.json.

The weird things is, when other people clones this project, they don't have the problem. only me...

One (maybe) pist, is when i put my mouse hover the 'moment' (of the import), i see this : 
.../node_modules/moment/moment like there is 2 moment folders, but it looks normal in the node_modules folder.

Thanks in advance!

***EDIT SOLVED :***

The problem was because i started the project with "docker-compose up" and not "npm run serve" on the FRONT. It started but i had this "moment" problem. Now it works well with the good console code to start the project ...

Comment: I had the same issue when using docker-compose. The solution was to delete all the docker images related to the app and rerun.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the import function with moment.js since exports is not defined for that module. So you have to use require. You can do this :

```
Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));
```

If you really want to use moment.js using import you can do this as well.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment

https://momentjs.com/docs/

[Webpack / typescript require works but import doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563578/webpack-typescript-require-works-but-import-doesnt)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

I tried this : 

Vue.use(require('vue-moment'));
moment.locale('fr');

Without any import and same error :
Failed to compile.

./src/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue-moment' in '/app/src'
(the vue-moment is present in node_modules).

I've also tested with your 2nd solution :
import * as moment from 'moment';
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

// Translate use vueJs
Vue.use(VueI18n);

// Vue use moment.js
Vue.use(VueMoment, {
  moment,
});

Same error still...

Comment: I suspect that most probably node_modules is in a different folder than it is supposed to be. Can u show the project layout?

Comment: Try following steps : remove the existing node_modules folder. Then delete package-lock.json file. Once done make sure you are the root of your project directory and install using npm install . See if this works and let me know.

Comment: Hi again,

Thanks but i solved the issue.
The problem was because i started the project with "docker-compose up" and not "npm run serve" on the FRONT. It started but i had this "moment" problem.

Now it works well with the good console code to start the project ...

Thanks and sorry for taking your time!