# NPM + Browserify error: ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I have two simple js files. One of them should be the module which exports its content which will be included by import command.

First testModule.js:

```
export function test() {
    console.log('teeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeest');
}
```

and main.js:

```
import * as test from "../src/js/testModule.js"

test.test();
```

In package.json I have two script commands. First to translate es6 to es5 and second to Browserify the es5 result because of modules. First one works. But the second throws me an error.

```
{
    "name": "examples-vue",
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
        "browserify": "^16.5.1",
        "core-js": "^3.6.5"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "es5": "babel ./src/js/main.js -o ./js/main.es5.js",
        "browserify": "browserify ./js/main.es5.js -o ./js/bundle.js",
        "build": "npm run es5 && npm run browserify"
    }
}
```

The result of the first command is this:

```
"use strict";

function _typeof(obj) { "@babel/helpers - typeof"; if (typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol") { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return typeof obj; }; } else { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; }; } return _typeof(obj); }

var test = _interopRequireWildcard(require("../src/js/testModule.js"));

function _getRequireWildcardCache() { if (typeof WeakMap !== "function") return null; var cache = new WeakMap(); _getRequireWildcardCache = function _getRequireWildcardCache() { return cache; }; return cache; }

function _interopRequireWildcard(obj) { if (obj && obj.__esModule) { return obj; } if (obj === null || _typeof(obj) !== "object" && typeof obj !== "function") { return { default: obj }; } var cache = _getRequireWildcardCache(); if (cache && cache.has(obj)) { return cache.get(obj); } var newObj = {}; var hasPropertyDescriptor = Object.defineProperty && Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor; for (var key in obj) { if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) { var desc = hasPropertyDescriptor ? Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key) : null; if (desc && (desc.get || desc.set)) { Object.defineProperty(newObj, key, desc); } else { newObj[key] = obj[key]; } } } newObj.default = obj; if (cache) { cache.set(obj, newObj); } return newObj; }

test.test();
```

And the second command throws an error: **ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'**

In other questions is still the same answer. Browserify does not work with es6 syntax. But It works with es5 file. What is wrong with this code? Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34569845/1529413?

Answer (score 0):

So the valid syntax for Browserify is

for import

```
import * as testModule from "./testModule.js";
import { test2module } from "./testModule2.js";
```

for export

```
module.exports.test = test;
module.exports.xxx = xxx;
```

or for export

```
export var test2module = {
    test2: test2,
    aaa: aaa
}
```