# Jest doesn't recognize awilix container

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, awilix

Here is my code:

```
babel.config.cjs
module.exports = {
    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'],
    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }]]
  }


jest.config.cjs
module.exports = {
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      isolatedModules: true,
    },
  },
};


Setup.ts
import awilix from 'awilix';
import express from 'express';
import CognitoSC from './Service/Cognito.js'
import authController from './Controller/Auth.js';

const app = express();
const container = awilix.createContainer({
  injectionMode: awilix.InjectionMode.CLASSIC
});


auth.test.ts
import request from 'supertest';
import app from '../Setup.js';

describe('Testing Authentication/Authorization', function() {
    it('responds with json', async function() {
      const response = await request(app)
        .post('/signin')
        .send('username=Test')
        .send('password=Testtest123$')
      expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
      expect(response.body.data.success).toEqual(true);
    });
  });
```

and I build it with `tsc` ("module": "es2022"). When I run `npx jest` I get an error saying

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createContainer')

>  8 | const container = awilix.createContainer({
```

Interesting thing that I noticed is that if I open `Setup.js` file which is generated by `tsc` and change the code from

`import awilix from 'awilix';`

to

`const awilix = require('awilix');`

and run `npx jest`, the tests pass without a problem. I'm little lost and can't figure out what is the problem. I also checked inside `Setup.js` and express is imported without a problem using ES6 syntax but why it can't do the same with awilix?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that awilix supports modules.

From their [readme](https://github.com/jeffijoe/awilix#usage) they say to use `const awilix = require('awilix')` .

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62554884/5618967) for more information about import/require/ES modules/commonJS.

Comment: This is strange, I changed my code in `Setup.ts` to this `import {createContainer, asClass, InjectionMode} from 'awilix';` and everything works ok

Comment: @Jakomo https://stackoverflow.com/a/34569845/5618967 does that fix it?

Comment: but awilix has it's types with `.d.ts` files